# Playwright recording test in TS instead of JS

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I have playwright installed with its VS code Extension (Playwright Test for VS code from Microsoft). The project is setup for JS and I have been recording tests with the plug in. It was creating JS files but for some reason, now, when I record a test with the plugin, it generates a TS file.

I would like it to record a JS file instead. Anyone with any idea where project settings are saved for this functionality.

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)